# Stay in edit mode when push to another view and go back IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In some cases I want my tableview in editmode when the view appears. To do this I set editMode = true when segue to the view and call setEditing in viewWillAppear method. When the view is in editing mode and the view is pushed to another view and popped back to this view, the table is not editable anymore. Could someone tell me how to stay in editing mode or do this a better way?

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.setEditing(self.editMode, animated: false)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple fix..

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if (editing){
        print("Editing")
        self.editMode = true
    }
    else {
        print("Done editing")
        self.editMode = false
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

TableViews have their own properties to track whether it is in edit mode or not:

```
yourTable.isEditing
```

So no need to add "editMode" to the table and manually set it whenever the table goes in or out of editing mode.